# Silverlight PathListBox Selecteditem

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

ı tryed all the ways  ı  know  but  its not work I  want  image Show pictures when ı click item of pathListBox  in silverlight here is my website you can see  what ı am trying Click to PhotoGalley than left lower corner Picture click on it than storyboard will  Show pictures  ı  want  click on images of PathListbox And bind it to image source   than  ı can see  big  Picture   here  tutorial of  create carosel & PathListbox  But  When I  do  lıke  they do  sample data create in expression blend  xap getting  bigger  ı   didnt  create sample data   ı  load  images  from images folder in client bin folder   here  my  website   [Http://forum.websayfaci.net](http://forum.websayfaci.net) 
 thx for your hellp

```
<ec:PathListBox x:Name="pathListBox1" Height="57.388" Canvas.Left="79" Canvas.Top="34" Width="280.248" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
            <ec:PathListBox.LayoutPaths>
                <ec:LayoutPath SourceElement="{Binding ElementName=path}" Distribution="Even" FillBehavior="NoOverlap"/>
            </ec:PathListBox.LayoutPaths>
        </ec:PathListBox>

<!--image sources coming from sample collection and this collection created in expreeion blend 4 -->

<Grid DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=pathListBox1}" Height="409" Canvas.Left="79" Canvas.Top="184" Width="247" d:DataContext="{Binding Collection[0]}">
                <Image Source="{Binding Property1}" Margin="0,0,0,8" Stretch="Fill">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                            <ei:HyperlinkAction TargetWindow="_tab" NavigateUri="http://websayfaci.net"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </Image>
            </Grid>
```

this xaml code work well  but  make your xap bigger.  now  ı try not  create collection  directly load images  from  my pictures folder to PathListbox source  till here  ok  but  when ı click any Picture on pathlistbox its not work  how to bind or how is work selected item  things

Comment: Please show the relevant code.

Comment: You want a smaller xap is what got from this? I would suggest cutting down on how many images you're adding to it, or at least optimize them to bring their file sizes down. I'm just guessing, but I would bet your images are at least twice the file size they could be. Otherwise may just not be understanding your question, it's kind of scattered my friend.

Comment: your respond is not what ı expected  and  is not answer of my question  mrs Chris   ı mean  its  not  work  when ı tryed to  selected Item of The PathListBox  ok  But  ı  desided  to not  use  PathListBox I  use  WirtualBook Picture Show now  ı  can  bind  easly image clicked event  But Thanks you Anyway